# CloudFoundry: cf push 10001 error

Tags: cloud-foundry

So I have deployed CF on AWS via microbosh using this minimal AWS example manifest:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/blob/master/example_manifests/minimal-aws.yml

After the deployment I try to deploy a sample application:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music

After running cf push I get this error message:

```
Uploading spring-music...

REQUEST: [2015-09-09T14:16:28+01:00]
PUT /v2/resource_match HTTP/1.1
Host: api.54.72.78.16.xip.io
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: go-cli BUILT_FROM_SOURCE / darwin

[{"fn":"META-INF","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"META-INF/MANIFEST.MF","sha1":"79e33dd52ebdf615e6696ae69add91cb990d81e2","size":25},{"fn":"WEB-INF","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/albums.json","sha1":"e579bae807f849fc3b4ff78cc6a83b5ab0b04533","size":5859},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties","sha1":"aedc9ea64c3a57ca1c55615685566dc49e848346","size":319},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties","sha1":"da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/AppInitializer.class","sha1":"3a07e3f4f6c50bd5c6f3eac783fbe97c14c93217","size":3572},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/SpringApplicationContextInitializer.class","sha1":"61d6f78b653e1e4751861abeef20d466177f5af8","size":6433},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/AbstractJpaRepositoryConfig.class","sha1":"39e2e702fd1c09ca7216df7e1bbec02daf92fb86","size":2592},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/AbstractLocalDataSourceConfig.class","sha1":"475f913c406816e3bb4493f648510792f424aa40","size":999},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/H2DataSourceConfig.class","sha1":"3825cc4f43ad40f7746ac78da51b3bfbb8289444","size":1533},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/LocalJpaRepositoryConfig.class","sha1":"ddaa697dd3011413bf4d1598f03d837c9625c5cc","size":937},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/MongoCloudConfig.class","sha1":"18b5288e23f90ad12055f6d5ee9c3b14355554ff","size":1054},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/MongoConfig.class","sha1":"90e8a86ce5fc8ee5f89e725f3cb09a267b20b6d2","size":1160},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/MongoLocalConfig.class","sha1":"8e855ec6953c59b952428bcf5a8f032e6a90a08b","size":1373},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/MySqlLocalDataSourceConfig.class","sha1":"cded621abcf36d4cfaa2da6e818aee343dd7ad3a","size":1015},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/MySqlRepositoryConfig.class","sha1":"6f04e9b7b06343e7b34ccca6fcd758b7b9662a1c","size":928},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/OracleRepositoryConfig.class","sha1":"00de296b1ec240027eacf321e668b52d1efb2e64","size":935},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/PostgresLocalDataSourceConfig.class","sha1":"f47f5e4fc489a1f28d8c1b22d1cce732fe506a7e","size":1040},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/PostgresRepositoryConfig.class","sha1":"99d18cc36d1810615d92a39f6e40a7c72e21adb8","size":946},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/RedisCloudConfig.class","sha1":"8e645137f9a1227dc835469f9f67958a3eca1314","size":1095},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/RedisConfig.class","sha1":"86df8731bafd853800c883359fb505a403a8c351","size":2923},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/RedisLocalConfig.class","sha1":"e6d84040fb8e9661d690425220e5f9c328937d2d","size":835},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/RelationalCloudDataSourceConfig.class","sha1":"60f1bd3ef0c46cef830748714cdb3039a2a5c663","size":1104},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/root","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/root/RepositoryConfig.class","sha1":"71acf4880aefcd0da84f58442eed79247641d7cc","size":685},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/web","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/web/WebMvcConfig.class","sha1":"941bb1bb46992e152ab39ef83df632954b63dc03","size":2987},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/domain","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/domain/Album.class","sha1":"ce720add4d17a7a5d89460eaa8fa7eabf8c7de66","size":2317},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/domain/ApplicationInfo.class","sha1":"03f0a39c4efb129205ac745b57e24fc75b6b161d","size":891},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/domain/RandomIdGenerator.class","sha1":"f7201c1358bbabb81586c412da58fe01aaca7c7e","size":921},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories/AlbumRepository.class","sha1":"f888ae33282d6ec2b6ef4faa7a61c8ffca702f45","size":371},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories/AlbumRepositoryPopulator.class","sha1":"0306e4a85aeebf26317abbf915f7c2a049b2ac4d","size":4237},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories/jpa","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories/jpa/JpaAlbumRepository.class","sha1":"eb51a0a178f029d037a7066052c1de3853f3a1a8","size":601},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories/mongodb","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories/mongodb/MongoAlbumRepository.class","sha1":"876a43bbdd5b136cbbac1f79260a4f088f687202","size":621},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories/redis","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories/redis/RedisAlbumRepository.class","sha1":"216965208e3dfee948d7bbbbd647160c6bbef4c4","size":6122},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/web","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/web/controllers","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/web/controllers/AlbumController.class","sha1":"115669023bc03d3ebeaa3d553701f6fb932721f9","size":3072},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/web/controllers/ErrorController.class","sha1":"4e365628fa758f91c5b4296a12cbfbbaa8840e30","size":1265},{"fn":"WEB-INF/classes/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/web/controllers/InfoController.class","sha1":"19af3943431748b0f965d647b1072b56e9a343f0","size":2839},{"fn":"WEB-INF/index.html","sha1":"a1ed27e2b2105f2ba0929718aaeaeeacac30b8b0","size":2090},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/angular-ui-0.4.0-2.jar","sha1":"8deff747c57910574bfa757abce9e1873dc015ce","size":25867},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/angular-ui-bootstrap-0.10.0-1.jar","sha1":"36425a16aca739ff1123661fa763333142bdf311","size":87876},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/angularjs-1.2.16.jar","sha1":"2a2d9eb9506e014fca469f2669697474c777a8c2","size":959292},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar","sha1":"83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0","size":445288},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar","sha1":"0235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8","size":4467},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar","sha1":"e49a5c0acee8fd66225dc1d031692d132323417f","size":119683},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/bootstrap-3.1.1.jar","sha1":"a11ab29de60b76fa111a2ca583de57abdbbcad26","size":271885},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar","sha1":"4fd4c6110e9bca3a655b717eb2e5920febb8403d","size":121757},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar","sha1":"f6f66e966c70a83ffbdb6f17a0919eaf7c8aca7f","size":62050},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool-1.3.jar","sha1":"03231230c1d7631b66a74d1c4653cfd65a6f9ea0","size":62086},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool2-2.0.jar","sha1":"4f8826f7a470c31f5089d73e3afa0d6761dc1b79","size":107063},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar","sha1":"5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94","size":313898},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/h2-1.3.162.jar","sha1":"fb381c2cb2805c7135cde33045955fb6e6fa94fd","size":1263688},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar","sha1":"78bcf608d997d0529be2f4f781fdc89e801c9e88","size":81271},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar","sha1":"87e473509a5a61ca9988c1c4dd71ed6c80c598ab","size":4507245},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final.jar","sha1":"fb74c7c9f3837701d5e0e33d393d998c18ceae3e","size":479539},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar","sha1":"3306a165afa81938fc3d8a0948e891de9f6b192b","size":102661},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar","sha1":"f2d0447bcdb27a48398215a33eb351b8a594e3a4","size":476575},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar","sha1":"f5e853a20b60758922453d56f9ae1e64af5cb3da","size":35058},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.3.3.jar","sha1":"7d8c5d79cc99995e21e6f955857312d8409f02a1","size":199621},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar","sha1":"3c304d70f42f832e0a86d45bd437f692129299a4","size":232248},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar","sha1":"63b77400b5f1cf83a81823562c48d3120ef5518e","size":915481},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar","sha1":"1ee2f2bed0e5dd29d1cb155a166e6f8d50bbddb7","size":780664},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar","sha1":"30c30512115866b6e0123f1913bc7735b9f76d08","size":711972},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar","sha1":"c71f2856e7b60efe485db39b37a31811e6c84365","size":60768},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar","sha1":"2ab6236535e085d86f37fd97ddfdd35c88c1a419","size":11209},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar","sha1":"ab1648fe1dd6f1e5c2ec6d12f394672bb8c1036a","size":16515},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jedis-2.6.2.jar","sha1":"b5572df5cedcc72fb12affd338ef34b628f98eff","size":330461},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jquery-2.1.0-2.jar","sha1":"0db1742ea52e14b25b7c4ab39d7a348324241567","size":156743},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar","sha1":"74aca283cd4f4b4f3e425f5820cda58f44409547","size":414240},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar","sha1":"5af35056b4d257e4b64b9e8069c0746e8b08629f","size":489884},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar","sha1":"b989c66514af8473bf8cf7368bbb7552da5879e3","size":419108},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar","sha1":"6b2835d687a706678591febfd47b077dcce41595","size":848399},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar","sha1":"9bfabe48876ec38f6cbaa6931bad05c64a9ea942","size":551290},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar","sha1":"562424e36df3d2327e8e9301a76027fca17d54ea","size":28688},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar","sha1":"7539c264413b9b1ff9841cd00058c974b7cd1ec9","size":8819},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"f1a538c0ba95442ccf9a5e897d9a9895a637c539","size":352833},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"295ecbf61e2313b4472947a1b3084022ba09e524","size":672348},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"2e13e181bec2da39d89f5154f64f1ab121d1bfe8","size":1249371},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-cloud-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"47384e4f2e3a5294284307cd0c1db36559487d8a","size":38823},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"4b107a7e73689ae33ada7e29943e7feee5b1dabb","size":62014},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"13015a0ff2a9bed4686a0f1d8d85a2ae57034e3a","size":978793},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"e446313c92026293805aa814815a8adbbdb5d292","size":135759},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"a7aea1dd2c5cde050d2d62833ec397d899a00854","size":978413},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"ccaf8f785382bdef27a0c287d2d75af7e5c8dccf","size":412790},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"6e8608622fd11205238d8d1363f099c2a638a0bf","size":185985},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-mongodb-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"dc0adbc87658c388e44622adca2bed85d187e563","size":466786},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"9756805b6e56e820067304c3156b434334ed7f46","size":652614},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"256abd04e9c25f84ef98b18e4b89051b8ec68ba2","size":205486},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"8fc09a51ca267726ffd284ab4de7c02f667da2ad","size":405717},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"b1f3ef4edfd5344207ed03c361e17bbdf3251c49","size":385454},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"5cac23b59532ffc19a3b2b6f4b59b84d16443132","size":248376},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"4d5066f31ea4b9c58957bf8c0c213b13ed44c1c5","size":667960},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar","sha1":"d6fd9778619ab87a41ae3aa879a53ee60f160c08","size":662385},{"fn":"WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar","sha1":"b6bd7f9d78f6fdaa3c37dae18a4bd298915f328e","size":47433},{"fn":"assets","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"assets/css","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"assets/css/app.css","sha1":"f1d528800480aa95bfc5dd74bee20d20231e858b","size":759},{"fn":"assets/css/multi-columns-row.css","sha1":"4681a9b61e2153a6bdfe3771949bb2802418b906","size":2962},{"fn":"assets/img","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"assets/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png","sha1":"a25c4705320fd63c33790e666872910e702b9bf6","size":8777},{"fn":"assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png","sha1":"84f613631b07d4fe22acbab50e551c0fe04bd78b","size":12799},{"fn":"assets/js","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"assets/js/albums.js","sha1":"ca8408a047e6c367de03ba851d5a2ccd73459635","size":6073},{"fn":"assets/js/app.js","sha1":"c3e731cc523e55e04c26e574b8d9baf27a9587e1","size":513},{"fn":"assets/js/errors.js","sha1":"f31d03be28698f9450bc1609ba37034f30665d57","size":1315},{"fn":"assets/js/info.js","sha1":"2d9efda6e52a8cc4498bd39e8b6bb0edf750d47a","size":198},{"fn":"assets/js/status.js","sha1":"9f5f323d09a60d84488bd1416bba51f8898df834","size":844},{"fn":"assets/templates","sha1":"0","size":0},{"fn":"assets/templates/albumForm.html","sha1":"cf901470d965fa3b380917308f88a18796c18a11","size":2518},{"fn":"assets/templates/albums.html","sha1":"61adbe9cadecca7a9c535c5566dffbce738ac7f6","size":1278},{"fn":"assets/templates/errors.html","sha1":"de30868fab77a1c0cc9e3f97af57835848edf561","size":797},{"fn":"assets/templates/footer.html","sha1":"34b0d0b86a0e44c3b055a79d3832943c2628edfc","size":37},{"fn":"assets/templates/grid.html","sha1":"208abe9d7f16bad64e07aaa6a8cbcc0dfc1c9335","size":1419},{"fn":"assets/templates/header.html","sha1":"12cb2fd327bc40622a95e998a55ab186aeca333d","size":1060},{"fn":"assets/templates/list.html","sha1":"59d1e52a81ccebb5f3445dd3bb398357b38d6cd6","size":1613},{"fn":"assets/templates/status.html","sha1":"70dcaeafba28003b22287fd977e051396e401fdb","size":421}]

RESPONSE: [2015-09-09T14:16:28+01:00]
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 99
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 09 Sep 2015 13:16:32 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Cf-Requestid: 2855109b-a277-470e-6eba-a5c2aecfd52e
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 7607de39-98ac-4e01-54aa-e8085cb09fb5::3bec65cd-58b5-4dd8-a700-22c0d3cb7579

{
  "error_code": "UnknownError",
  "description": "An unknown error occurred.",
  "code": 10001
}
```

Here is the full error from cloud controller logs:

https://gist.github.com/RichardKnop/da4921418958c04ad638

Any ideas how to debug this? Is there something missing in my CF manifest?

I am running out of ideas. I am using release 215.

Answer (score 0):

The log line you mention has an Errno::ENOSPC error when attempting to contact the blobstore, which seems to imply that there is no more space on the blobstore (which is where the resources are stored).

If you are using the example minimal manifest, you are using NFS as your blobstore. I would check to make sure that:

1. Your api VMs all have the NFS mounted properly (it should be mounted under /var/vcap/nfs)
2. That your NFS VM has adequate space.